# How can i fill an svg area inside the stroke?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

i got this svg.

```
<svg id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 283.73 268.03"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke:#231f20;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:6px;}</style></defs><path class="cls-1" d="M227.34,231.69c9.24-1.11-85.47,12.9-85.47,12.9l31.28,15c4.65,0,37.16-9.81,37.16-9.81,13.94-5.68,20.13-2.58,20.13-2.58,37.16,9.81,50.29,2.26,50.29,2.26s0-71-62-74.5c-2.24-.13-6.32-3.62-8.28-4.65a235.64,235.64,0,0,0-23.7-10.71,253.36,253.36,0,0,0-36-11.1c-7.16-1.63-14.4-2.95-21.68-3.91-3-.4-7-.13-9.79-1.42-10.27-4.86-7.15-14-10.1-23.45,0,0-2.58-15-5.68-13.94,0,0,.52-17-6.19-21.16,0,0-.52-18.06-4.65-17,0,0-11.35-40.26-26.83-37.68,0,0-5.68-10.32-10.33-9.81,0,0-6.71-2.61-9.8,0,0,0-6.71-2-15-16.5,0,0-10.32,3.1-10.32,6.71L32.25,29.88S30.7,33.49,14.7,20.07c0,0-5.68,3.62-4.13,9.81l4.65,10.84c2.58,1.55-2.59,18.58-2.59,18.58S5.41,76.85,7,82.53l2.58,6.71c-4.13-.52-5.16,5.16-5.16,5.16v27.87s-3.1,16.51,0,20.64c0,0-3.1,8.78,10.32,19.62,0,0,3.61,28.9,13.93,40.25L19.86,227l1,3.62c-4.13,0-3.61,10.32-3.61,10.32,10.87,1,21.78,1.75,32.69,2.17,5.34.21,13.27-1.51,18.29-.36,3.89.89,7.74,6.82,11.12,9.79a87.75,87.75,0,0,0,13.16,9.6c3.42,2,7.64,3.87,11.25,2.19a4.53,4.53,0,0,0,2.47-2.54c.68-2.08-.74-4.22-2.14-5.89a83.43,83.43,0,0,0-36.85-25.28c1.13-4.24,2.46-8.5,3.29-12.79-3.28,11.61,17,16,24.15,17.44,15.47,3,31.55,3.21,47.25,3,12.6-.2,25.18-.89,37.74-1.84C195.38,235.25,211.68,231.69,227.34,231.69Z"/></svg>
```

and i want to make an event when mouse is on the image to fill the svg area inside the stroke from bottom to top with a color.

i have try this

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  const path = document.querySelector("#Layer_2");
  console.log(path);

  path.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    path.setAttribute("fill", "blue");
    console.log("tocaste el lobo");
  });

  path.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    path.setAttribute("fill", "transparent");
    console.log("saliste del lobo");
  });
});
```

but doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<svg id="Layer_2" width=200 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 283.73 268.03"><defs><style>
svg {
  fill: none;
}

.cls-1{
  stroke: #231f20;
  stroke-width: 6px;
}

.LoboTop {
  fill: white;
}

.LoboTop:hover {
  fill: blue;
  animation: 1.5s Reveal;
}

@keyframes Reveal {
  0% { clip-path: inset(0 0 100% 0) }
  100% { clip-path: inset(0) }
}

</style>
</defs>

<path class="cls-1"
 id="Lobo" 
 d="M227.34,231.69c9.24-1.11-85.47,12.9-85.47,12.9l31.28,15c4.65,0,37.16-9.81,37.16-9.81,13.94-5.68,20.13-2.58,20.13-2.58,37.16,9.81,50.29,2.26,50.29,2.26s0-71-62-74.5c-2.24-.13-6.32-3.62-8.28-4.65a235.64,235.64,0,0,0-23.7-10.71,253.36,253.36,0,0,0-36-11.1c-7.16-1.63-14.4-2.95-21.68-3.91-3-.4-7-.13-9.79-1.42-10.27-4.86-7.15-14-10.1-23.45,0,0-2.58-15-5.68-13.94,0,0,.52-17-6.19-21.16,0,0-.52-18.06-4.65-17,0,0-11.35-40.26-26.83-37.68,0,0-5.68-10.32-10.33-9.81,0,0-6.71-2.61-9.8,0,0,0-6.71-2-15-16.5,0,0-10.32,3.1-10.32,6.71L32.25,29.88S30.7,33.49,14.7,20.07c0,0-5.68,3.62-4.13,9.81l4.65,10.84c2.58,1.55-2.59,18.58-2.59,18.58S5.41,76.85,7,82.53l2.58,6.71c-4.13-.52-5.16,5.16-5.16,5.16v27.87s-3.1,16.51,0,20.64c0,0-3.1,8.78,10.32,19.62,0,0,3.61,28.9,13.93,40.25L19.86,227l1,3.62c-4.13,0-3.61,10.32-3.61,10.32,10.87,1,21.78,1.75,32.69,2.17,5.34.21,13.27-1.51,18.29-.36,3.89.89,7.74,6.82,11.12,9.79a87.75,87.75,0,0,0,13.16,9.6c3.42,2,7.64,3.87,11.25,2.19a4.53,4.53,0,0,0,2.47-2.54c.68-2.08-.74-4.22-2.14-5.89a83.43,83.43,0,0,0-36.85-25.28c1.13-4.24,2.46-8.5,3.29-12.79-3.28,11.61,17,16,24.15,17.44,15.47,3,31.55,3.21,47.25,3,12.6-.2,25.18-.89,37.74-1.84C195.38,235.25,211.68,231.69,227.34,231.69Z"/>


<use xlink:href="#Lobo" class="LoboTop" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks mate!. Another question, what if i want to fill it from the bottom to the top and not instantly?

Comment: @JuanFedericoDiLeo I'd repeat the drawing and put them together above each other, then in the top one (hidden but blue filled) animate a mask to reveal it. Or, probably easier, fill it with a gradient and animate the gradient.

Comment: And another question if i want to do this with two different svgs and with differents colors between theres a way to change hover with ids?

Comment: Without JavaScript no, because the `use xlink:href=theId` clone will inherit the color. But, with JavaScript you can clone the SVG and use different colors.